# How to properly display json records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have json data as follows

```
[{
            "id": 2332860,
            "name": "NAME 1",
            "capping": [{
                "quantity": 1,
                 "rule":[{"frequency": 'bad' }]
            }]
},

{
            "id": 77777,
            "name": "NAME 2",
            "capping": [{
                "quantity": 2,
                 "rule":[{"frequency": 'good' }]

            }]
}]
```

Here is how I first retrieve the **id and name** data via api response and everything is works fine as per the code below

```
obj=JSON.parse(response)
print(obj)

obj.each do |val|
  id, name = val['id'], val['name']

  puts "ID:   #{id}"
  puts "Name: #{name}"

end
```

Here is how the view looks like

```
<ul>
  <% obj.each do |val| %>
    <li><%= val['id'] %> - <%= val['name'] %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**What am trying to achieve now:**

Now I want to access **quantity** from capping and **frequency** from rule. To this effect I implemented this code below but gets
**error undefined local variable or method capping**

```
obj=JSON.parse(response)
print(obj)

obj.each do |val|
  id, name = val['id'], val['name']

  puts "ID:   #{id}"
  puts "Name: #{name}"

#get quqntity
  val.capping.each do |cap|
    quantity = cap['quantity']

    puts "QTY:   #{quantity}"

      #get frequency
      cap.rule.each do |r|
        frequency = r['frequency']

        puts "FRQ:   #{frequency}"


     end


  end

end
```

Any idea on why am getting the error above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `capping` the same as you do `id` and `name`.  Ruby thinks `val.capping` is a method.  Try using this:

```
val[:capping]
```

or

```
val['capping']
```

Comment: Thanks Sir David,it works. I can retrieve all the data now. Please one more question. do you have an idea on how overall view.html.erb will now look like judging from the code above between thanks

Comment: You need to make `obj` a instance variable by adding an `@` to it:  `@obj=JSON.parse(response)`.  Then you can access `@obj` from your view `view.html.erb`.  Sorry, I can't format in comments, but after that it should render like:

<ul>
    <li> 2332860 - NAME 1</li>
    <li> 2332860 - NAME 2</li>
</ul>